# Вызов внешних программ

Tags: windows, c++

Есть в программе CListCtrl и нужно его вывести на печать. НО, т.к. я этого делать не умею)) то буду экспортировать в файл с HTML-разметкой, т.е. запишу туда свою таблицу.

Вопрос: Как вызвать программу просмотра (браузер) используемый по умолчанию и передать туда сразу этот файл (как будто мы открыли файл двойным кликом). Ну и идеально было бы еще вызвать печать страницы. Все это желательно без участия пользователя.

Comment: 1. Записать файл в %TMP%
2. ShellExecute
3. ????
4. PROFIT!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Решил вопрос через

```
ShellExecute(0, 'Open', 'file.html', NULL, NULL, SW_SHOW);
```

Comment: ShellExecute(0, 'print', 'file.html', NULL, NULL, SW_SHOW);//?

Comment: @Сирошка Не работает(( Но поробовать стоило.

Comment: По-моему, Internet Explorer регистрирует глагол "print"...

Answer (score 2):

Первая часть задачи решилась на удивление просто

```
#include <stdio.h>
main ()
{
  system ("start c:\\users\\avp\\ttt.htm");
}
```

Правда, если браузер запущен, то просто открывается новая страница в нем. Естественно a.exe завершается, а страница остается. Т.е. вопросы далога надо решать как-то иначе.

Comment: От меня ускользает разница между этим и аналогичным заминусованным ответом...

Comment: @karmadro4, дело в слове start.

Comment: @karmadro4, по сути разницы нет, страница в обоих случаях появляется в браузере.

К сожалению, это еще один пример некомпетентности оценщиков.

Comment: @mikillskegg,

> Для вызова неисполняемых файлов через механизм сопоставления типов > файлов 
    достаточно просто ввести имя файла в командной строке.  
> Например, команда
    WORD.DOC запускает приложение, сопоставленное расширению имени 
> файла .DOC.

Answer (score -1):

system("C:\\адрес\\файла\\файл.html");